# Controling shapes of line connection

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering how can I change the connection in red circle, so that it 
looks like the one just at its right, with a good symmetry :[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning,fit}

\tikzset{
  ncbar angle/.initial=90,
  ncbar/.style={
    to path=(\tikztostart)
    -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
    -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
    -- (\tikztotarget)
  },
  ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=1.3cm,>=stealth',bend angle=20,auto,
    place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10mm},
    red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
    every label/.style={red},
    every node/.style={scale=.4},
    dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt}]


\node [initial, place] (l0)  {$l0$};
\node [place,below=of l0,xshift=2cm] (l1) {$l1$};
\node [place,below=of l0,xshift=-2cm] (l2) {$l2$};

\path (l0) edge [in=30, out=60,loop] node{eq0} (l0)
       edge [in=150, out=120,loop] node[above]{set0} (l0)
       edge [bend left] node{set1} (l1)
       edge [bend right] node[left]{set2} (l2)
  (l1) edge [in=60, out=30,loop] node[above]{set1} (l1)
       edge [in=-60, out=-30,loop] node[below]{eq1} (l1)
       edge [bend left] node[right]{set0} (l0)
       edge [bend right] node[above]{set2} (l2)
  (l2) edge [in=120, out=150,loop] node[above]{set2} (l2)
       edge [in=240, out=210,loop] node[below]{eq2} (l2)
       edge [bend right] node[left]{set0} (l0)
       edge [bend right] node[below]{set1} (l1);


\node [place] (l2-3)  [left=1.8cm of l2] {wait};
\node [place] (l2-2) [above=of l2-3,label=above:$x\le k$]{req};
\node [place] (l2-4) [left=of l2-3]                       {cs};
\node [initial, place, left=of l2-2] (l2-1)  {idle};


\path (l2-1) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{try reset$\{x\}$ } (l2-2)
      (l2-2) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{set \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l2-3)
      (l2-3) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{enter $x > k$} (l2-4)
           edge [bend right] node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{retry \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l2-2)
      (l2-4) edge node[align=center,pos=0.5]{exit} (l2-1);



\node [place] (l3-4) [right=1.8cm of l1]                      {cs};
\node [initial, place,above=of l3-4] (l3-1)  {idle};
\node [place] (l3-2) [right=of l3-1,label=above:$x\le k$]{req};
\node [place] (l3-3)  [right=of l3-4] {wait};


\path (l3-1) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{try reset $\{x\}$ } (l3-2)
      (l3-2) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{set \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l3-3)
      (l3-3) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{enter $x > k$} (l3-4)
           edge [bend right] node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{retry \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l3-2)
     (l3-4) edge node[align=center,pos=0.5]{exit} (l3-1);




\node [inner sep=3.2cm, draw, fit=(l0)(l1)(l2)] (rec1) {};
\node [inner sep=3.2cm, inner xsep=3.8cm, draw, fit=(l2-1)(l2-2)(l2-3)(l2-4)] (rec2) {};
\node [inner sep=3.2cm, ,inner xsep=3.8cm, draw, fit=(l3-1)(l3-2)(l3-3)(l3-4)] (rec3) {};

\node [dots,label=-180:set1] (set1) at ($(rec2.north east)!0.1!(rec2.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-180:enter1] (enter1) at ($(rec2.north east)!0.3!(rec2.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:retry1] (retry1) at ($(rec2.north west)!0.5!(rec2.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:exit1] (exit1) at ($(rec2.north west)!0.3!(rec2.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:try1] (try1) at ($(rec2.north west)!0.7!(rec2.north east)$) {};

\node [dots,label=0:set2] (set2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.1!(rec3.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=0:enter2] (enter2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.3!(rec3.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:retry2] (retry2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.5!(rec3.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:exit2] (exit2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.7!(rec3.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:try2] (try2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.3!(rec3.north east)$) {};

\node [dots,label=0:set1] (setp1) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.1!(rec1.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=0:eq1] (eq1) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.3!(rec1.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=180:set2] (setp2) at ($(rec1.north east)!0.1!(rec1.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=180:eq2] (eq2) at ($(rec1.north east)!0.3!(rec1.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:set0] (set0) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.3!(rec1.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:eq0] (eq0) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.7!(rec1.north east)$) {};

\draw [-] (set1) -- (setp1);
\draw [-] (set2) -- (setp2);
\draw [-] (enter1) -- (eq1);
\draw [-] (enter2) -- (eq2);


\draw [-] (exit1) to[ncbar=10mm] (eq0);


\draw [-] (exit2) to[ncbar=-10mm] (eq0);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can define two new helper coordinates and draw lines via those. Replace the `\draw` lines with `ncbar` with

```
\path (eq0) ++(0,1cm) +(-1cm,0) coordinate(x1) +(1cm,0) coordinate(x2);
\draw [-] (exit1) |- (x1) -- (eq0) -- (x2) -| (exit2);
```

and you get

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=1.3cm,>=stealth',bend angle=20,auto,
    place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10mm},
    red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
    every label/.style={red},
    every node/.style={scale=.4},
    dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt}]


\node [initial, place] (l0)  {$l0$};
\node [place,below=of l0,xshift=2cm] (l1) {$l1$};
\node [place,below=of l0,xshift=-2cm] (l2) {$l2$};

\path (l0) edge [in=30, out=60,loop] node{eq0} (l0)
       edge [in=150, out=120,loop] node[above]{set0} (l0)
       edge [bend left] node{set1} (l1)
       edge [bend right] node[left]{set2} (l2)
  (l1) edge [in=60, out=30,loop] node[above]{set1} (l1)
       edge [in=-60, out=-30,loop] node[below]{eq1} (l1)
       edge [bend left] node[right]{set0} (l0)
       edge [bend right] node[above]{set2} (l2)
  (l2) edge [in=120, out=150,loop] node[above]{set2} (l2)
       edge [in=240, out=210,loop] node[below]{eq2} (l2)
       edge [bend right] node[left]{set0} (l0)
       edge [bend right] node[below]{set1} (l1);


\node [place] (l2-3)  [left=1.8cm of l2] {wait};
\node [place] (l2-2) [above=of l2-3,label=above:$x\le k$]{req};
\node [place] (l2-4) [left=of l2-3]                       {cs};
\node [initial, place, left=of l2-2] (l2-1)  {idle};


\path (l2-1) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{try reset$\{x\}$ } (l2-2)
      (l2-2) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{set \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l2-3)
      (l2-3) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{enter $x > k$} (l2-4)
           edge [bend right] node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{retry \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l2-2)
      (l2-4) edge node[align=center,pos=0.5]{exit} (l2-1);



\node [place] (l3-4) [right=1.8cm of l1]                      {cs};
\node [initial, place,above=of l3-4] (l3-1)  {idle};
\node [place] (l3-2) [right=of l3-1,label=above:$x\le k$]{req};
\node [place] (l3-3)  [right=of l3-4] {wait};


\path (l3-1) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{try reset $\{x\}$ } (l3-2)
      (l3-2) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{set \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l3-3)
      (l3-3) edge node[align=center, pos=0.5]{enter $x > k$} (l3-4)
           edge [bend right] node[align=center, pos=0.5, swap]{retry \\ reset$\{x\}$} (l3-2)
     (l3-4) edge node[align=center,pos=0.5]{exit} (l3-1);




\node [inner sep=3.2cm, draw, fit=(l0)(l1)(l2)] (rec1) {};
\node [inner sep=3.2cm, inner xsep=3.8cm, draw, fit=(l2-1)(l2-2)(l2-3)(l2-4)] (rec2) {};
\node [inner sep=3.2cm, ,inner xsep=3.8cm, draw, fit=(l3-1)(l3-2)(l3-3)(l3-4)] (rec3) {};

\node [dots,label=-180:set1] (set1) at ($(rec2.north east)!0.1!(rec2.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-180:enter1] (enter1) at ($(rec2.north east)!0.3!(rec2.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:retry1] (retry1) at ($(rec2.north west)!0.5!(rec2.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:exit1] (exit1) at ($(rec2.north west)!0.3!(rec2.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:try1] (try1) at ($(rec2.north west)!0.7!(rec2.north east)$) {};

\node [dots,label=0:set2] (set2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.1!(rec3.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=0:enter2] (enter2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.3!(rec3.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:retry2] (retry2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.5!(rec3.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:exit2] (exit2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.7!(rec3.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:try2] (try2) at ($(rec3.north west)!0.3!(rec3.north east)$) {};

\node [dots,label=0:set1] (setp1) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.1!(rec1.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=0:eq1] (eq1) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.3!(rec1.south west)$) {};
\node [dots,label=180:set2] (setp2) at ($(rec1.north east)!0.1!(rec1.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=180:eq2] (eq2) at ($(rec1.north east)!0.3!(rec1.south east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:set0] (set0) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.3!(rec1.north east)$) {};
\node [dots,label=-90:eq0] (eq0) at ($(rec1.north west)!0.7!(rec1.north east)$) {};

\draw [-] (set1) -- (setp1);
\draw [-] (set2) -- (setp2);
\draw [-] (enter1) -- (eq1);
\draw [-] (enter2) -- (eq2);


\path (eq0) ++(0,1cm) +(-1cm,0) coordinate(x1) +(1cm,0) coordinate(x2);
\draw  [-] (exit1) |- (x1) -- (eq0) -- (x2) -| (exit2);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```